# iOS iPhone ZBar cannot scan EAN13+2

Tags: ios, iphone, barcode-scanner, zbar-sdk, zbar

I am using ZBar SDK 1.3.1 and installed it using CocoaPods and my app is built for base SDK 5.0.

Trying to scan barcodes with format EAN13+2 (EAN13 plus two digit add on, [more info](http://www.barcodemaking.com/EAN-13_+_2_Digit_Supplement.html)) I experience some issues. Before updating to 1.3.1 to support 64-bit it worked quite well. Sometimes it just scanned the add on digits and not the first thirteen digits.

After upgrading to 1.3.1 it doesn't work at all. I have tried experimenting with the symbology set to tweak it but with no luck.

The current symbology set is

```
// Disable all
[scanner setSymbology: 0 config: ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE to: 0];
// Enable EAN13+2
[scanner setSymbology:ZBAR_EAN2  config:ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE to:1];
```

I have also tried adding

```
[scanner setSymbology:ZBAR_EAN13 config:ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE to:1]
[scanner setSymbology:ZBAR_EAN13 config:ZBAR_CFG_MIN_LENGTH to:15] // Ean code is 15 digit long
```

but also without luck. Using this config is just captures the thirteen first digits.

Here is an example bar code

[Barcode EAN13+2 example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mf2v.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to do is perform two separate scans. Once you obtain the first 13 digit EAN, don't close the camera, just reconfigure the scanner and scan for the +2. Then close the camera and just append them together.

Comment: Yes that became the work around. It doesn't work flawless but better working than not working in this case.